# What mechanism does a brushless motor use to generate electricity

Tags: voltage, motor

I have observed that when you spin the rotor of a motor, electricity is generated, but i don't understand how this applies a brushless motor that has its magnets as the rotor, all that is happening is that you are spinning the magnets, how does this generate electricity?

Comment: You're pushing the magnetic field through the coils which generates multi-phase AC voltage. This might be a better question for Physics:SE.

Comment: See Biot-Savarts law

Answer (score 1):

Same way as in a DC motor, except you get AC since a brushless motor doesn't have a commutator.  It actually doesn't matter if the magnets are in the stator or in the rotor, only that the magnets move relative to the windings.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Maxwell-Faraday law of induction.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations), and [Faraday's Law of Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction)

> The voltage induced in a closed circuit is proportional to the rate of change of the magnetic flux it encloses.

In the case you are referring to, the rotating magnets cause a changing magnetic flux that the coils in the stator enclose with each turn of the magnet wire.

You can deduce a couple of things from this simple law without getting into the differential equations.

1. If you spin the shaft faster, the voltage will go up proportionally.
2. The voltage at a given RPM will be proportional to the number of turns in the stator.